# Using a single JFrame across multiple classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am working on a video game in Java that so far has a main menu class and a class for the game. As I have it set up right now, each class uses its own JFrame, which means that when the user clicks "start game", the main menu JFrame closes and the games JFrame opens. Obviously this is not ideal and I would like to have both classes use the same JFrame, however I really don't know how to go about this and internet searches have not been helpful.

The class for my main menu is:

`public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
...
}`

I have it set up right now so that my Game class imports my Frame class, but when I try to make the JFrame display elements from my game nothing comes up. So my question is:

How do I use one single JFrame across multiple classes?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: use `JFrame` for the main frame and `JPanel` for the subsequent frames of your game.

Comment: My main class uses a JLayeredPane, is it possible to put this within a JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then needing to pass a reference of the main frame to each of the child panels, which might expose parts of the program you don't want them to have access to (as an example), you should use something like a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) and use the main frame as the main display hub, switching out the panels as you need to

Check out [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more examples

Comment: Ok so I am now using panels, is it possible to put a layered

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve.  `CardLayout` will allow to determine which panel should be active on the screen, allowing to occupy the entire available space.  Something like a `JLayeredPane` will allow you layout multiple panels which can be layered over each other, but you become responsible for laying them out.  You can place any type of component onto a container using a `CardLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having each class be its own frame, you can have one frame, with several classes manipulating it.  I would probably set something up like this:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        super("Cool Game!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class Game {
    private final MainFrame mainFrame;

    public Game(final MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        mainFrame.setContentPane(createGamePanel());
    }

    private JPanel createGamePanel() {
        //...
    }
}

public class MainMenu {
    private final MainFrame mainFrame;

    public MainMenu(final MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
    }

    public void showMainMenu() {
        mainFrame.setContentPane(createMainMenuPanel());
    }

    private JPanel createMainMenuPanel() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain to me what adding `private` and `final` in front of MainFrame in your Game class does?

Comment: Sorry, my Eclipse adds those by default.  `private` makes it only accessible to the Game class.  `final` makes it a constant value - you can't change what "mainFrame" is once the constructor sets it.  Some of the other answers may be a little easier if you're not used to Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use just one frame at overall game. And there should be many JPanels for different contents.

Deciding content and switching should be like this :

```
switch( currentState )  {

   case introduction: 
        setContentPane(new IntroductionPanel());
        break;
    case insideGame:
        setContentPane( new GamePanel() );
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: Right idea, there is probably a better ay of aching it though - IMHO

Comment: Should this be in the class for the frame?

Comment: it depends your  implementation, but this is for giving you idea how to change content.

Answer (score 0):

Use cardLayout to switch panels 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html